# Threads vs Processes

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the thread limitations when working on Linux compared to processes for network/IO-bound apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609469/what-are-the-thread-limitations-when-working-on-linux-compared-to-processes-for-n)

What is meant by context switches in threads or processes ? Also which is better : Threads or Processes ? I mean which is more space efficient and which is more time efficient ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609469/what-are-the-thread-limitations-when-working-on-linux-compared-to-processes-for-n/3705919#3705919).

Comment: It's not my fault your answers are ill-informed and airy. Make yourselves known.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can say one is better than the other - it depends what you are doing.

There is a detailed overview of context switches here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

In the most basic sense a context switch is when the processor pauses execution of a task to do another task.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have to remember that threads may be your only choice if your OS is embedded and doesn't support multiple processes ;)