# How does pthread implemented in linux kernel 3.2?

Tags: linux, pthreads

all,

The code below comes from "Advanced Programing in Unix Environment", it creates a new thread, and prints the process id and thread id for main and new threads.

In the book, it said that in linux, the output of this code would show that two threads have different
process ids, because pthread uses lightweight process to emulate thread. But when I ran this code in Ubuntu 12.04, it has kernel 3.2, printed the same pid.

so, does the new linux kernel change the internal implementation of pthread?

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t ntid;

void printids(const char *s) {
  pid_t     pid;
  pthread_t tid;
  pid = getpid();
  tid = pthread_self();
  printf("%s pid %u tid %u (0x%x)\n",
         s, (unsigned int)pid, (unsigned int)tid, (unsigned int)tid);
}

void *thread_fn(void* arg) {
  printids("new thread: ");
  return (void *)0;
}

int main(void) {
  int err;
  err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thread_fn, NULL);
  if (err != 0)
    err_quit("can't create thread: %s\n", strerror(err));
  printids("main thread: ");
  sleep(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514464/difference-between-pthread-and-fork-on-gnu-linux

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent article on the switch Linux made to NPTL in kernel 2.6: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library  and a shorter article that explains some of the shortcomings of the older threading model, LinuxThreads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On Linux `pthread` uses the `clone` syscall with a special flag `CLONE_THREAD`.

See the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) of `clone` syscall.

> CLONE_THREAD (since Linux 2.4.0-test8)
>
> If CLONE_THREAD is set, the child is placed in the same thread group as the calling process. To make the remainder of the discussion of CLONE_THREAD more readable, the term "thread" is used to refer to the processes within a thread group.
>
> Thread groups were a feature added in Linux 2.4 to support the POSIX threads notion of a set of threads that **share a single PID**. Internally, this shared PID is the so-called thread group identifier (TGID) for the thread group. Since Linux 2.4, calls to getpid(2) return the TGID of the caller.

And in fact, Linux do [change its thread implementation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), since [POSIX.1 requires](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) threads share a same process ID.

> ```
>    In the obsolete LinuxThreads implementation, each of the threads in a process
>    has a different process ID.  This is in violation of the POSIX threads
>    specification, and is the source of many other nonconformances to the
>    standard; see pthreads(7).
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Linux typically uses two implementations of pthreads: [LinuxThreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads) and [Native POSIX Thread Library(NPTL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library), although the former is largely obsolete. Kernel from 2.6 provides NPTL, which provides much closer conformance to SUSv3, and perform better especially when there are many threads. 
You can query the specific implementation of pthreads under shell using command:

`getconf GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION`

You can also get a more detailed implementation difference in [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/).