# Context switching in different thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multitasking

Is there any way to perform a preemptive same-thread context switch?

I am pretty sure that is not the right way to describe what I am looking for, so here is a longer description:
I want the same type of behavior as POSIX `ucontext_t` or `boost::context`. There are probably others I am not aware of. I don't know the official term for it, but basically they allow single-threaded multitasking. Both those libraries require "cooperative" code, that is, the currently running "thread" must explicitly perform a context-switch.
I am looking for a way to force a context switch. I assume this would have to be done from a separate thread (real OS thread). I would want to have an array of "contexts", frozen execution paths, and be able to switch to any one I choose, freezing the current execution.

I don't care whether the solution uses a separate thread for the "switcher" (I assume this is required) or not.
I am fine with Java/C#/C++/C solutions, or a combo of C/C++ and some minimal Assembly.
I would like if it was cross platform (Windows and Linux) and cross compiler (GCC, MinGW and VS, assuming a c/c++ solution), but am aware this is not likely to be possible. At a minimum it should work on Windows with at least one compiler.
I am fine using almost any library or compatibility layer needed (e.g. `boost` or some sort of 'POSIX on Windows' layer)

I hope this isn't asking for to much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-routines

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283294/how-to-make-thread-in-c-without-using-posix-library-pthread-h)

Answer (score 1):

[boost.fiber](http://github.com/olk/boost-fiber) - can be programmed like boost.thread but provides user-land threads

Comment: I don't think there is a boost.fiber. At least, I just looked for it and couldn't find it.