# Code a simple thread with C and assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to code a simple user-level thread library as an exercise for my OS course. As the first step, I am trying to run a program and jump to a function leaving the first program. The code so far is this:

The initial program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define STACK_SIZE (sizeof(void *) * 512)


void proc2() //This is the function that should run as the thread.
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        printf("Here I am!\n");
        sleep(0.5);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void* malloc_stack() //used to malloc the stack for the new thread. 
{
    void *ptr = malloc(STACK_SIZE + 16);
    if (!ptr) return NULL;
        ptr = (void *)(((unsigned long)ptr & (-1 << 4)) + 0x10); //size align
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int *bp, *sp; 
    sp = malloc_stack();
    bp  = (int*) ((unsigned long)sp + STACK_SIZE);
    proc1(&proc2,sp,bp); //the actual code that runs the thread. Written in assembly
    assert(0);
}
```

And then I wrote a simple assembly code called proc1 that takes three arguments, pointer to a function (used as the instruction pointer), stack pointer and base pointer and replace the current registers with these values. The code I wrote is:

```
.globl  proc1
proc1:   
movq    %rdx, %rbp        #store the new base pointer
movq    %rsi,%rsp         #store the new stack pointer  
jmp     %rdi              #jump to the new instruction pointer.
```

But when I run this code, what I get is a segmentation fault. Please help me to find the error here.

Well it's working correctly when I ran it under GDB using the following commands:

```
gcc -g test.c switch.s
gdb a.out
run
```

but when it rus alone as in ./a.out, it doesn't work!!!! 
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for starters, you probably don't want "&proc2"...  Q: What's your compiler/debugger? GCC and GDB?  Have you tried stepping through your code under the debugger, looking at key variables along the way?  If not, why not?

Comment: When encountered with a segfault, a programmer typically fires up a debugger to see where exactly the seg fault happened, especially if the segfault is 100% repeatable. You should too, and then possibly update the question.

Comment: @paulsm4 It's ok to use `&` when taking address of a function, and many people prefer it because (arguably) it makes it clearer what's going on.

Comment: To add on @hyde's comment: A ken of coredumps and gdb on Linux boxes is highly advisable.

Comment: @paulsm4 my compiler is GCC and debugger is GDB I didn't try stepping through the code because I didn't know how to, I'm just a starter. And even when I did use GDB (looking at a tutorial, the output of it seems to make no sense to me) I edited the question according to the output I got. the assembly code is supposed to retrive three values from the memory the new stack pointer, the new base pointer and the new instruction pointer for my thread and store the stack pointer and base pointer in their registers and then jump to the location of the instruction pointer.

Comment: @hyde the additional unnecessary code was because I used a template I had once. As I told before, I'm a starter. Changed that now. But the result is the same.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283294/how-to-make-thread-in-c-without-using-posix-library-pthread-h

Comment: do you still get the segmentation fault? Which OS are you using?

Comment: @didierc I don't get it when I run it in GDB. It runs fine in GDB and produces the desired output but get the segfault when run alone. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my VMWare virtual machine (which runs upon Windows 7)

Comment: I believe the `sleep(0.5)` might not do what's expected. I believe `sleep()` takes an int and 0.5 will then be truncated down to zero.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your code to include the assembly instructions directly in the C source as follow:

```
void proc1(void (*fun)(), int *sp, int *bp){
    register int *sptr asm ("%rsi") = sp;
    register int *bptr asm ("%rdx") = bp;
    register void (*fptr)() asm ("%rdi") = fun;

    asm (
        "mov %rdx, %ebp\n"
        "mov %rsi, %esp\n"
        "jmp *%rdi\n"
    );
}
```

The above code ensures that the parameters to `proc1` are in the right registers (although your code seems to be correct wrt the abi). Note the `*` in front of the `jmp` argument, which my version of gnu as warned about when I first tried your code.

With the above function, and code compiled with `-g` you should be able to debug it properly (use the `breakpoint` instruction on `proc1` and `info registers` to check the content of the cpu).

---

**The issue** is actually on the `%rsp` pointer, which must always be equal to or greater than `%rbp` (the stack grows downward). Simply passing bp instead of sp to `proc1` in main should fix the issue:

```
 proc1(&proc2, bp, bp);
```

2 small remarks:

- don't forget to give `proc1` prototype in the C code for the asm version:

  ```
  extern void proc1(void (*)(), int *, int *);
  ```
- the `sleep` libc function only take `unsigned long`, not `float`.

  ```
  sleep(1);
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the issue. Actually I have confused sp with bp. Thank you for the reminder on the function prototype and I wonder why GCC didn't warn me about sleep? Maybe I should have used -Wall option. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know. I didn't use `-Wall` either, though I ought to (it's good practice).

Answer (score 2):

Your `movq` at the top of your assembly are (well, "were" before you edited :-) ) written as

```
movq dst,src
```

but your `movq` before the `jmp` is written `movq %rax,%rsp` and `%rsp` is clearly the desired dst.  That's obviously wrong, not sure about anything else.

Comment: -1: This is clearly in AT&T syntax, and the order of the operands is src, dest in AT&T syntax. You seem to confuse Intel syntax with AT&T syntax. In Intel syntax the order of the operands is dest, src.

Comment: @nrz: the OP edited his question; earlier, he was pulling parameters from the stack into registers, using the (dst,src) order.  Presumably he was not assembling one line with one syntax and the next with another, which made at least one line incorrect.  My best guess at the time was that he grabbed the (dst,src) order from some compiler output, but it's possible he got it from elsewhere.

Comment: @torek OK, the question has been edited after your answer. `movq %rsi,%rsp` (the current code) seems correct to me, being equivalent to to `mov rsp,rsi` in Intel syntax.

Comment: @nrz sorry for not informing my changes. Yes I did edit it. Now it works in GDB but not alone. Can you guess why??