# how to do update process in background

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I have to do some update operation on the background. Because it takes so many times. Therefore I shouldn't wait for this operation. User should send any different comment during the update operation.

My OS is Linux and I use C programing Lang. as far as my search, I have to use fork() function for this.

Any different idea?

Comment: What? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Why? I am going to do 2 operation at the same time with fork(). Do you have any different idea?

Comment: You could use [pthreads or clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514464/difference-between-pthread-and-fork-on-gnu-linux).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things parallelly, multi-process(fork) or multi-thread(pthread) could be used.

You can fork a child process to do the update operation, or you can use pthread_create to do the samething.